# Configure .htaccess file for a mean stack application

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-deployment

I am deploying my mean stack web application on a shared a2 hosting that supports nodejs.
I have to reconfigure the .htaccess file to reroute the users to the localhost with the port of the front end using the following sample:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:55555/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:55555/$1 [P,L]
```

The website recommends using ports between 49152 and 65535 (inclusive).
I am using port 55555 for frontend and 50000 for backend but I need to configure the .htaccess to route backend requests too like it does with the frontend cause now the website opens as a frontend project only without a connection between the frontend and the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Angular proxy configurations.. Angular needs to be configured to route backend requests from a relative path "/api/" for example to the backend port "localhost:port/api/" using proxy.
You can refer to this link for how to do it.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c

Hope it helps.